# NEMA 5-15 on 6awg wire

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have an outlet with a 14-50 recepticle in it.I want to add a 5-15 to the box on the same circuit. I've done this before with a 14-30 and 5-15 on 10awg without issue. Since I now have 6age wire, what's the best way to connect the 5-15?

Answer (score 5):

Generally you speaking, **you can't do that**. There may be some very specific exceptions relating to a receptacle with a cooktop/stove/oven, but you would need a specific exception to allow it.

If the question were: How do I *replace* a 50A circuit with 6 AWG wire with a 15A or 20A circuit and matching receptacles, the answer is to use wire nuts to connect the 6 AWG wires to 12 AWG or (if 15A circuit) 14 AWG wires. But as stated, "no" is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a 5-15 receptacle on a 50A breaker. (not on a 30A breaker either).  So, reuse of that wire run will require changing the breaker to an appropriate value e.g. 15A (or 20A due to the exception that allows 15A receptacles on 20A circuits).

Breakers are $10.

To attach a #6 wire to a receptacle you will need to pigtail using either really large wire nuts, or ILSCO "MAC Block Connectors".

Comment: It passed inspection. Was the inspector wrong?

Comment: Did it pass inspection, @J'e, with a _14-50_ receptacle on #10 wire and a 50A or 30A breaker, or did it pass inspection with a _5-15_ receptacle on a 50A or 30A breaker? I'm guessing it's the former, since you're asking to change to the latter. If you made that change then had it inspected again, it would _not_ pass because you're not allowed to have a 5-15 receptacle on a breaker with rating higher than 20A. That's because 30A passing through a 5-15 would start a warm, toasty fire while the 30A breaker thinks nothing is wrong.

Comment: I've had this for a few years now but you're starting to make me worry. The inspection was for adding a new run that included a new breaker, wire, and a 2 gang outlet with 2 receptacles.  Breaker was 2pole-30, Wire was 10/3, outlets were 14-13 and 5-15.  The 5-15 was using one of the hots and a neutral from same 10/3 Romex. I don't know what this is called but the Romex passed through the outlet without being cut.  In other words, there was a continuous wire running from the breaker all the way through both outlets.

Comment: The inspector missed it. Everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: Yeah, that was a flub on the inspector's part. The 15A socket is not allowed on a 30A circuit.  If that was legal, every laundry room would be that.